# Visual Studio Code - Debuging a Node.js application with TypeScript and auto-restart

Tags: node.js, gulp, visual-studio-code, nodemon

I'm trying to debug a Node.js application using TypeScript in VSCode. I want :

- To simply hit "F5". I don't want to start `nodemon` or something else *manually* in a terminal.
- The TypeScript files to be automatically recompiled when they are changed.
- The application to be automatically restarted when TypeScript files are recompiled.

[***Here is my best try***](https://github.com/electrotype/vscode-issue-restart) [project on GitHub].

Using this project :

- I hit "F5" and the application starts correctly in debug mode. This is done by calling a `Gulp` task which uses `nodemon` to start the application using `--debug-brk=5858`.
- If I add a breakpoint in `app.ts`, on the "*response.end(...)*" line, it works well.
- But when I change the `app.ts` file, for example by modifying "*Date1*" for "*Date2*", the recompilation is done properly but the debugging session ends!!

I'm not sure what I'm missing, since in `launch.json` I do have an "attach" section with the `"restart": true` property.

Anybody has a working example of a Node.js application that can be debugged in VSCode with automatic TypeScript files recompilation and automatic application restart?

UPDATE : thanks a lot to Andre. It seems that achieving what I want is currently not possible. Here's [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17381) created to add the feature required to make it possible.

Answer (score 3):

Just having a "Attach" launch config in the launch.json is not enough. You actually have to run it. From your description I got the impression that you are not running it because your 'F5' runs a gulp task instead.

What should work is the following: Run your gulp task in a terminal and then use 'F5' to launch the "Attach" launch config. It should attach to the node process initially and later reattach if it detects that nodemon has restarted node.